# how to disable movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, movieclip

I am using Adobe Flash CS5, Action Script 3.0. I want to disable my movie clip. How to do that?

My code:

```
var index:Array = ([0,1,2,3]);

var radioGroup1:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("question1");

rb1.group = radioGroup1;
rb2.group = radioGroup1;
rb3.group = radioGroup1;
rb4.group = radioGroup1;

b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitclick,false);


function submitclick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (radioGroup1.selectedData == null)
    {
        b1.mouseEnabled = false;
        //ExternalInterface.call("Test","Please selecte one answer");
        //return;
    } else {
        if (radioGroup1.getRadioButtonIndex(radioGroup1.selection) == 2)
        {
            myscore +=  10;
        }
    }

    if (compquest>=maxquest)
    {
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 6");
    }
    else
    {
        MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndStop(1, "Scene " + questions[compquest++]);
    }
}
```

I want to disable this b1 movieclip. So anyone could tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If, by disable, you mean to make it unclickable and faded like a disabled button. Just reduce the alpha a bit and set its mouseEnabled property to false.

```
function submitClick(event:MouseEvent){
    b1.alpha = .6;
    b1.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

This way the user will not be able to click it and it appear disabled.

Comment: I am used b1 is Button label in flash components.so its not work

Comment: Thanks ya...How to enable that b1?

Answer (score 0):

First you could write, because `event.target` is p1:

```
function submitclick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.mouseEnabled = false;
}
```

On the other hand, the `condition` you want to evaluate in your `if statement` is probably false:

```
radioGroup1.selectedData == null
```

Therefore the associated code isn't executed:

```
b1.mouseEnabled = false;
```

You should test in your function and before your if statement:

```
trace(radioGroup1.selectedData == null);
```

Comment: Thanks ya..And How to enable that b1?

Comment: @Sathis Jo  event.target.mouseEnabled = true;

Comment: Its not work...I need user click one option in radio button by the b1 will enable?

Comment: this my code:if (radioGroup2.selectedData == null) 
{
 b1.mouseEnabled = false;
}
else
{
 if (radioGroup2.selectedData !== null)
 b1.mouseEnabled = true;

}